# Where can I get email notifications on any transactions to/from an address I do not control?

Tags: transactions

There was at least one site that did this I remember.

Comment: None of the below solutions work to get an email when a transaction is confirmed

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- http://www.Blockchain.info/wallet <-- add address as watch-only.
- http://bitnotify.com
- http://bitcoinwhoswho.com
- http://txnotify.com

Comment: The only one that still works is  http://www.bitcoinmonitor.net/. I don't see an option for watch-only at blockchain.info.

Comment: Only blockchain.info is still up among these, and I could add a watch-only address but I never got the notification email for an incoming transaction on that address.

Comment: https://txnotify.com works as of february 2020. It's very simple as well. You can get email notifications every time your bitcoin address receives money. Or when a transaction reaches a specified number of confirmations. disclaimer: I made it.

Answer (score 4):

http://bitcoinwhoswho.com/

you can set up free transaction alerts for any bitcoin address here

Comment: Don't post to your own site without full disclosure

Comment: unfortunately they don't support segwit yet

Comment: @Ossip are you fucking serious?

Answer (score 3):

http://bitping.net will send you email notifications on any transactions to/from a bitcoin address.

Comment: This site can’t be reached bitping.net’s server IP address could not be found. DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

Answer (score 2):

As of October 2015, the only services that still seem to offer email notifications (for free) for transactions on an address (for which they don't need the private key) appear to be:

- http://blockchain.info/wallet with the option to add a wallet as watch-only. It doesn't seem 100% reliable (it missed a few transactions initially), but now it seems to work and gives a notification pretty much instantly.
- http://blockonomics.co with which I had a temporary problem with validating the confirmation email, but seems to work otherwise. Notification emails arrive a bit later (maybe they wait for the transaction to be confirmed or something like that?).

Comment: Yes, blockonomics waits for two confirmations on blockchain before sending out email Source: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Blockonomics

Answer (score 1):

Try http://blockonomics.co  . I use it get email notifications and check balance, sends a nice formatted email

Comment: Registration on the site is broken, email verification fails with a Python traceback.

Comment: I was able to register and still using the site. Try clearing your browser cache before signup. If this doesn't work mail to webmaster@blockonomics.co

Answer (score 1):

https://cryptocurrencyalerting.com might be what you're looking for.  They will monitor a BTC or ETH wallet address and notify you whenever a transaction occurs. 
 Supports email/sms/telegram/slack/etc.  ERC-20 coins are accepted.
(Disclosure: I am affiliated with the creators of this service)

Comment: Are you affiliated with that site? If so, you must disclose your affiliation, or are considered spam.

Comment: I added my disclosure

Answer (score 0):

You can add that address to [blockchain.info/wallet](http://blockchain.info/wallet), as watch-only if you prefer, and enable email notifications.

(didn't try that myself with watch-only addresses, so this might fail)

Answer (score 0):

https://walletnotify.com/

- unlimited notifications
- very quick response time

Answer (score 0):

http://bitnotify.com

- Easy setup.
- Sends crafted notifications.
- Watch-only address monitoring service. Works without the private key.

Comment: Internal Server Error The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying this out:

https://cryptocurrencyalerting.com/my-alerts.html

It works for btc but also other currencies. It's free and online based, so no app to install.